# ipTables, how to block all services requests on port 80 for an IP?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

On a linux server/router,
I want to block port 80 only for one IP (example : 1.2.3.4 )
I have been given this example :

```
### Block Incoming Port Requests (BLOCK PORT)
# To block port 80 only for an ip address 1.2.3.4, enter:
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 80 -j DROP
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 80 -j DROP
```

I'd guess only the first line is needed.
I don't understand what this line does:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Comment: -1 You write `"I dont understand why this line :"`  You don't understand why this line what?  Why it works? Why it doesn't work? What it does? What do you expect it should do?

Comment: Oh the stressed man put a -1, yay...

Comment: It's called quality control. It's good that you edited your answer, i'll now remove the -1

Comment: Now why don't you try looking at the website that the example comes from http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-examples.html    and then read the description "#8:Drop Private Network Address On Public Interface

IP spoofing is nothing but to stop the following IPv4 address ranges for private networks on your public interfaces. Packets with non-routable source addresses should be rejected using the following syntax:"

Comment: Which part of the above iptables command do you not understand, exactly? If you know what all the other lines mean, you should get that one as well, as they're all very similar.

Comment: @geewee : I dont understand one : $ iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 80 -j DROP. I dont understand why ut s not suffisant to use only this one : $ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 80 -j DROP... The entire example provides these 2 lines, as a noob, I feel only the 1st is needed : 
"To block port 80 only for an ip address 1.2.3.4, enter:"
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 80 -j DROP
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 80 -j DROP

Comment: @ArchiT3K  You do only need the first.  The last one is to stop spoofing, it'd go on a NAT Router but apparently most distros deal with spoofing anyway.  The first line could go on either a NAT Router or a computer on your LAN.

Comment: @barlop thank you. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: @barlop  it's got nothing to do with preventing IP spoofing and NAT router.

Comment: @geewee ... yes, i have been wondering... I really misunderstand this line utility. Dropping IP 1234 is done. Well. Theorically, it s done, done to death. nope ?

Comment: @geewee Think about what eth1 might possibly be in that example and look at the website he got it from. See my comment. I even quote the title above that example, and the description from the website the example comes from, that says it's for anti-spoofing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block an attackers ip address called 1.2.3.4, enter **only**:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

Comment: That cybercities website that you got the second line from, doesn't really follow best practices...People that are big on iptables are not fans of that page.  For example if spoofing were to be done manually with iptables, a better way is  apparently https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/   do edit..find..anti-spoofing  and see the example.

Answer (score 0):

You should first consult the command's manual page if you do not understand why/how it works. From `man iptables`:

> [!] -p, --protocol protocol
>
> The protocol of the rule or of the packet
>   to check.  The specified protocol can be one of tcp, udp, udplite,
>   icmp, esp, ah, sctp or the special keyword "all",  or it  can  be  a
>   numeric value, representing one of these protocols or a different one.
>   A protocol name from /etc/protocols is also allowed.  A "!" argument
>   before the protocol inverts the test.  The number zero is equivalent
>   to all. "all" will match with all protocols and is taken as default
>   when this option is omitted.
>
> [!] -s, --source address[/mask][,...]
>
> Source specification. Address can be either a network name, a hostname, a network IP address (with /mask), or a plain IP address. Hostnames will be resolved  once only, before the rule is submitted to the kernel.  Please note that specifying any name to be resolved with a remote query such as DNS is a really bad idea. The mask can be either a network mask or a plain number, specifying the number of 1's at the left side of the network mask. Thus, a  mask  of  24  is  equivalent  to 255.255.255.0.   A "!" argument before the address specification inverts the sense of the address. The flag --src is an alias for this option.  Multiple addresses can be specified, but this will expand to multiple rules (when adding with -A), or will cause multiple rules to be deleted (with -D).
>
> -j, --jump target
>
> This specifies the target of the rule; i.e., what to do if the packet matches it.  The target can be a user-defined chain
>   (other than the one this  rule  is  in), one  of  the special builtin
>   targets which decide the fate of the packet immediately, or an
>   extension (see EXTENSIONS below).  If this option is omitted in a rule
>   (and -g is not used), then matching the rule will have no effect on
>   the packet's fate, but the counters on the rule will be incremented.
>
> [!] -i, --in-interface name
>
> Name  of  an interface via which a packet
>   was received (only for packets entering the INPUT, FORWARD and
>   PREROUTING chains).  When the "!" argument is used before the
>   interface name, the sense is inverted.  If the interface name ends in
>   a "+", then any interface which begins with this name will match.   If
>   this  option  is omitted, any interface name will match.
>
> tcp
>
> These extensions can be used if `--protocol tcp' is specified. It
>   provides the following options: 
>   [..]
>
> [!] --destination-port,--dport port[:port]
>
> Destination port or port range specification.  The flag --dport is a convenient alias for this option. [..]

Therefore, the iptables command you are asking about reads: 'drop (`-j DROP`) TCP packets (`-p tcp`) from IP addresses 192.168.1.0-192.168.1.255 (`-s 192.168.1.0/24`) that are directed at port 80 (`--dport 80`) on this host (`-A INPUT`) and coming in on interface eth1 (`-i eth1`).'

Note that if the `-t` flag is not specified, `-t filter` is implied (this is also mentioned in the manual).

**Update (based on comment from OP):**
The above `iptables` line does not have anything to do with packets coming from IP address 1.2.3.4, and should probably be left out if the server/router does not have to block packets originating from the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

Comment: that s not an answer, excuse me. And I already read it. ...

Comment: How does my post not answer the question "As a iptables noob, I d guess only the first line is needed. I dont understand what this line does: `$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 80 -j DROP`". My post explains exactly that particular line.

Comment: Well, you do explain this line. But I dont understand why it is need to block 1.2.3.4 ...

Comment: @ArchiT3K: I see. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you re the man. Thanks to all of you. A light turns on in my head. Bon weekend

Comment: He questioned Why it is NEEDED(questioning what it does in that context),and all you stated what what it does on one level, but you misunderstood the purpose of it.If u see my comment(yet you deny what the website it came from said its purpose is),I showed you the purpose of it, and then you'd see the reason y I told the OP that it is not needed. Your update paragraph at the end might answer the question of why it is or is not needed,but there you are only stating what the OP said in comment.And ur entire post before your update paragraph at the end, does not address why it is or isn't needed.